# Finding number is present in sequence

Tags: python-3.x

I need to find out whether a given number is present in a given sequence. Sequence is an arithmetic progression with common difference of 2

Ex Input1 -  5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, . . .
for this sequence key is 19 so it is present i the sequence output would be True. 
For input2 - be 4,6,8,10...
Given key is 15 so it is not present output should be False.
I have written the code but it is only working for first set of input which is odd numbers .Its failing for input2 which is even

```
arr = 4,6,8
n=10
b=max(arr)
l=[]
if b>n:
    c=b
else:
    c=n
d=arr[1]-arr[0]
for i in range(1,c+d+1,d):
    l.append(i)
if n in l:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Output 1 - True
output2 - False

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `range`'s smart implementation of `__contains__` to get a one-liner O(1) solution:

```
print(6 in range(2, 10, 2))
# True
print(5 in range(2, 10, 2))
# False
```

And an extreme example to show how fast and scalable this is (the size of the `range` does not matter):

```
from timeit import Timer

print(min(Timer(lambda: 1_000_000_000 in range(2, 1_000_000_003, 2)).repeat(1000, 1000)))

# 00032309999999990957
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the real problem, which is they haven't set the correct endpoints on their range.